# Why does my website redirect in some browsers for some users?

Tags: redirect, iis

My organization recently launched a new website. In order to keep good search engine ranking we used a 301 redirect in IIS to point the old traffic to the new site. However, when doing this our internal site was also pointed to the new site,  and now on some devices it wants to redirect to the new site. I have removed the redirect from the internal site and restarted iis, and the app pool. In IE the site redirects but in chrome it does not for the devices that are not working. Is there another way to resolve this issue?

Comment: That’s probably just caching - especially Chrome is really hard-core when it comes to caching redirects. Try and clear the browsing history, that usually helps.

Comment: I cleared that cache in IE and closed the browser. I have even reset the settings in some and it resolved the issue yesterday. Today the issue is happening again.

Comment: Could it still be cached somewhere on the web server where iis is installed?